# Going to next page using Paginated Queries gives the same result as previous page - React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using @tanstack/react-query to get data from a server. The first set of data renders fine. When I click on the next button, the API call happens and I get the next set of data, but the data being displayed is not correct. I get to see only the previous data.

Please advice.

This is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  useQuery,
  useQueryClient,
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  keepPreviousData,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Example />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

function calculateOffset(currentPage, pageSize) {
  if (currentPage <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
}

async function fetchProjects(pageNumber) {
  console.log("aaapageNumber", pageNumber);
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=${calculateOffset(
      pageNumber,
      10
    )}`
  );
  return data;
}

function Example() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);

  const { status, data, error, isFetching, isPlaceholderData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["projects", page],
    queryFn: () => fetchProjects(page),
    placeholderData: keepPreviousData,
    staleTime: 5000,
  });

  // Prefetch the next page!
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isPlaceholderData && data?.next) {
      queryClient.prefetchQuery({
        queryKey: ["projects", page + 1],
        queryFn: () => fetchProjects(page + 1),
      });
    }
  }, [data, isPlaceholderData, page, queryClient]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        In this example, each page of data remains visible as the next page is
        fetched. The buttons and capability to proceed to the next page are also
        supressed until the next page cursor is known. Each page is cached as a
        normal query too, so when going to previous pages, you'll see them
        instantaneously while they are also refetched invisibly in the
        background.
      </p>
      {status === "pending" ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : status === "error" ? (
        <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
      ) : (
        // `data` will either resolve to the latest page's data
        // or if fetching a new page, the last successful page's data
        <div>
          {data &&
            data.results.map((project) => (
              <p key={project.name}>{project.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
      <div>Current Page: {page + 1}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setPage((old) => Math.max(old - 1, 0))}
        disabled={page === 0}
      >
        Previous Page
      </button>{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPage((old) => (data?.next ? old + 1 : old));
        }}
        disabled={isPlaceholderData || !data?.next}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
      {
        // Since the last page's data potentially sticks around between page requests,
        // we can use `isFetching` to show a background loading
        // indicator since our `status === 'pending'` state won't be triggered
        isFetching ? <span> Loading...</span> : null
      }{" "}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my StackBlitz URL:[Stackblitz Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/currying-wave-vbvi8m?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A110%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `calculateOffset` has a bug - the current page number is 0-based, but since `calculateOffset` does the equivalent of `Math.max(currentPage - 1, 0) * pageSize`, you have to go to page 2 to start retrieving values beyond the first page.

Comment: @Josh CAn you give me the fixed calculateOffset?

Comment: What about `function calculateOffset(currentPage, pageSize) { return currentPage * pageSize; }` ?

Comment: I tried. Still the same. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-babycat-neh09n?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A81%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A22%2C%22startColumn%22%3A81%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A22%7D%5D

Comment: Are you sure about that? The codesandbox link you give still has the old `calculateOffset`. See https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/objective-hill-d86673

Comment: the link you gave me is from a previous one. Try this: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-babycat-neh09n?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A81%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A22%2C%22startColumn%22%3A81%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A22%7D%5D

Comment: If I go to the https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-babycat-neh09n link that you gave me, I see the incorrect `calculateOffset`. If you use the https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/objective-hill-d86673 link that I gave you, it has a corrected `calculateOffset` function, and everything seems to work.